# Problem with PNT proof

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic

I am struggling with some expression involving Möbius formula. I try to understand the first equality of the following

> [image]

For knowledge, in this sum, $S(x,y)$ is defined by

> [image]

where $P+(n)$ means the greatest prime factor of $n$.
I guess there are some Möbius formula or maybe even Mangoldt stuff I am not getting.
If someone can provide me with help I'd be so grateful!

Comment: $\mu(n)\log{n}$ is the sum, over all the primes dividing $n$, of the $\mu(n)\log{p}$. Now, summing over $n \in S(x,y)$ and $p|n$ is the same as summing over $p \leq y$ and $n \in S(x,y)$ divisible by $p$. When $p$ is fixed, it's the same to sum over the $n \in S(x,y)$ divisible by $p$ as to sum over the $m \in S(x/p,y)$ (and take $n=pm$).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  I think you will enjoy using typset [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here.  It will help Readers to have a more self-contained problem posed in the body of your Question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem! Sometimes I spend time on -not so hard- stuff!